# Workaround for Chrome not handling backward date change in Windows

Tags: cookie, google-chrome, windows-7, expires

I'm heavily making use of cookies for a website. Their expiry period is set to 1 day.
My preferred test browser is Chrome 28, Windows 7.

For a test, I need to change the date of my OS back to eg the previous month ( eg. July 28th).
Obviously, doing so expiries the cookies (created on August 28th). But the problem is that all  newly created cookies (as of July 28th) immediately expire. The feelong, and the Chomium bug database make me think that Chrome caches in some way the system date : I must close Chrome and restart it again to be able to store cookies again.

Is there a workaround to this ?

Comment: Cookies not my strong point but I'm sure you can edit the cookies using firebug, right click the cookie and click edit, then edit the values.

Comment: [The bug is here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17155), by the looks of it. If you want to perform the test, can you not close chrome (end process), change time, open chrome, set cookie and move time forwards. Moving time forwards doesn't appear to be affected by the bug.

Comment: I'd prefer not to ask tester to do that trick (because they might have forgotten it, and give up). I saw the bug report in the bug database, didn't thought such a bug could be arround for 4 years ...

Answer (score 1):

As a developer myself I wouldn't even call that a bug, more of a snafu. Pulling the rug out from under an application like that and expecting it to all continue to work perfectly is simply asking too much out of your software. I'd have ignored that request too. Why not file the bug with the OS vendor (aside from the fact that MS just chuckles at bug reports and leaves it as is); I mean shouldn't all OSes be capable of overriding their child application settings (sar)?

Anyway, as for this question, Chrome doesn't have that feature ATM. It can do it but it isn't available as an easy to use button and that doesn't seem to be functionality which is usable by extensions (there doesn't seem to be any that do it).

This means that, unless I'm wrong, you'll need to find another solution. I can think of a few. First, just use one of the browsers which Brendons' link pointed to which didn't fail (IE8 or Opera).

The next option you might try is taking advantage of Chrome sessions: 
    Options > On startup: reopen the pages that were open last time > Close

This will at least save your state but does require that you still open Chrome again. You can fill in the blanks by monitoring for the window to close and running it again when it does. I'd roll my own app for this but you could try this (untested) app if you like: http://www.door2windows.com/undoclose-reopen-closed-folders-applications/

If you'd like to take this to the next level you can use multiple sessions and then make shortcuts for each using the cmd line: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3018/google_chrome_force_restore_previous_session_command_line/